# Need add to my jQuery function infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

He needs to do a loop by acting in this way:

```
    $(window).load(function(){ 
        $('.slogan').delay('2000').fadeOut('300', function(){
                    $('.slogan2').fadeIn('slow').removeAttr('display');
        });
    });
```

div `.slogan` for 3 seconds and div `.slogan2` for 3 seconds and 3 seconds after the return to the div `.slogan` - and so on to infinity.

Can someone please add something to my code?

Comment: please explain yourself better

Answer (score 2):

The following will overlap the fades

```js
function fade(delay, speed) {
  $('.slogan1').delay(delay).fadeToggle(speed);
  $('.slogan2').delay(delay).fadeToggle(speed, function() {
    fade(delay, speed)
  });
}

fade(2000, 1000);
```

```css
.slogan {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
.slogan {
  background: blue;
}
.slogan2 {
  background: green;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slogan slogan1"></div>
<div class="slogan slogan2"></div>
```

The following will play the fade one after the other

```js
function fade(delay, speed) {
  var slogan1 = $('.slogan1'),
      slogan2 = $('.slogan2');
  
  slogan1.delay(delay).fadeOut(speed, function() {
    slogan2.fadeIn(speed, function() {
      slogan2.delay(delay).fadeOut(speed, function() {
        slogan1.fadeIn(speed, function() {
          fade(delay, speed)
        });
      })
    });
  });
}

fade(2000, 1000);
```

```css
.slogan {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.slogan {
  background: blue;
}
.slogan2 {
  background: green;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slogan slogan1"></div>
<div class="slogan slogan2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in the following way:

HTML:

```
<div class="slogan">slogan</div>
<div class="slogan2" style="display: none;">slogan2</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
        doInfiniteLoop(3000, 1000);
    });


function doInfiniteLoop(delayTime, fadeTime){
        $('.slogan').delay(delayTime).fadeOut(fadeTime,function(){
                        $('.slogan2').fadeIn(fadeTime,function(){
                            $('.slogan2').delay(delayTime).fadeOut(fadeTime,function(){
                                $('.slogan').fadeIn(fadeTime, function(){
                                    doInfiniteLoop(delayTime, fadeTime);
                                });
                            });
                        });
        }); 

}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AgilePlayers/8zpq548w/1/)

Comment: I think you need to use setInterval function instead of setTimeout for infinte loop here

Comment: No, because it's inside the loop that it's calling, so you only want it once.  `setInterval` would be used if inside the `$(window).load`

Comment: While this is answer is slightly incomplete, the principle is correct - the `setTimeout` will initiate immediately so `doLoop` will be called every 3 seconds regardless of how long the animation takes.  To use this, you could tweak the timeout value to 9000 and add fadeout/fadein.  But this is a valid approach and shows what needs to be done.

Comment: Yes now I also see that. It is correct approach and don't necwssary to use setInterval here

Comment: Strange - why edit so that it's the same as someone else's answer?  The original approach was valid if a bit subject to timing issues, now it just looks like of a copy of the other two answers.

Comment: Sorry, honestly  I havent read other answers... I as well upvoted Pete answer due to the fact his solution is better. Thats all. Nothing less, nothibg more. Sorry if you see it differently.

Answer (score 0):

Move the animation to a separate function and call it when it's finished, the long version would be:

```
function animateSlogan() {
    $('.slogan')
        .delay('3000')
        .fadeOut('slow', function() {
            // when fadeout complete, start next fadeIn
            $('.slogan2')
                .fadeIn('slow')
                .delay('3000')
                .fadeOut('slow', function() { 
                    // when fadeout complete, fadein the original as it's not at the start
                    $('.slogan').fadeIn('slow', function() {
                        // when fadein complete, start again
                        animateSlogan();
                    });
                })
        });
}

$(function() { 
    animateSlogan();
});
```